# Cannot remove rows comparing dates in my SQLite db Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

I am trying and searching for a while now without success to remove specific rows in my db table.

I'd like to do this as a result in comparison between DATE record value and nextday value.

I thought this would do the work

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM Planned_expenses_table WHERE DATE <= date('now','+1 day')";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.execSQL(sql);
    db.close();
```

But it did not.

Any suggestion? I am currently storing column DATE values with the pattern `"YYYY-MM-DD"` which is the same returned by `date()`. 
 Logcat doesn't show any exception.
So what is wrong with this piece of code? Thank you in advance.

**EDIT** : i've just noticed that if i change `<=`  in `>` the rows are deleted, but this is very strange since saved dates are older

Comment: You have not told us which dates you want to remove.

Comment: @CL. i wanted to remove every record from the table that had the value of the field DATE older than tomorrow date. anyway i managed to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I managed to achieve the hoped result.**

Apparently i was saving the dates in the form `YYYY-M-D` instead of the one written in the question. Thats why the order check `<=` was misbehaving.

Answer (score -1):

Why not calculate the date then pass in the actual value.

```
var tomorrow = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
string sql = $"DELETE FROM Planned_expenses_table WHERE DATE <= '{tomorrow.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")}')";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

db.execSQL(sql);
db.close();
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response but android studio seems not able to resolve DateTime and TimeSpan, how can i import them?